# Make List Available to all Windows in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

A list of products is used through a WPF application. The list lstProducts is created in the business tier of the application. The list is fairly stable over time ... products only updated every 6 months.

How can that list be instantiated in C# such that it is available throughout the application?

My C# `Class` creates a list

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{
public class Products
{
    public class Product
    {
        public Int64 ProductId { get; set; }
        public string FileAs { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Product> lstFileAs { get; set; }

    public Products()
    {
                    //populate lstFileAs
    }
}
}
```

ComboBoxes on various forms are databound as follows

```
products = new Products());
cboProducts.DataContext = products;
cboProducts.ItemsSource = products.lstFileAs;
cboCustomer.DisplayMemberPath = "FileAs";
```

Let us please consider it as read that we all prefer to avoid global variables. However we are putting a new front end on an old and widely used application which does use global variables. The old application is written in VB6 and runs well in spite of using global variables. We are instructed to make the minimum changes to avoid unnecessarily introducing bugs.

Comment: Please define "global variables". Technically, there is no such thing in C#. However, `static` members are often used in the same way that a true global variable would, and people sometimes use the word "global" to describe a `static` member.

Comment: As far as the question itself goes, it is not clear what you mean by "available throughout the application". What parts of your program need access to this list? Are you using it only in C# code? Or do you need access/binding in XAML? What have you tried so far? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies for the poorly formulated question. Let's forget about the term 'global variables'.The lstFileAs is databound using C# to a number of comboboxes on different windows. We would like that list to be instantiated once so that data doesn't have to be pulled from the database multiple times.

Comment: I would simply declare the list as data in your XAML resources somewhere (e.g. in App.xaml, using `XmlDataProvider` or other convenient declaration mechanism), then bind to that resource throughout. You can load the resource from code (e.g. as static property backed by `Lazy<T>`) to access it from C# where/if needed. Without [a good, minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult if impossible to know exactly what would be best in your specific scenario.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have amended the code example to show how the products list is created and how it is databound on each form

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ObjectDataProvider and CollectionViewSource in App.xaml (for instance) and reference that in your project. I demonstrate here a possible implementation. This code assumes you create a GetProducts() method.

App.xaml:

```
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ProductsObjDataProvider" 
                            ObjectType="{x:Type BusinessObjects:Products}"
                            MethodName="GetProducts">                
        </ObjectDataProvider>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ProductsView" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsObjDataProvider}}"/>
```

To bind a combobox:

```
                <ComboBox  Name="cboProducts"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FileAs"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsView}}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProductID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Crowcoder. Is there a C# equivalent to the example you have given in App.xaml?

Comment: Xaml goes in App.xaml, not c#. This example I have given is an edited version of what I am currently doing in a c# project.

Comment: We prefer to minimise the use of xaml to keep the code flow as close as possible to the original application. Is it possible to instantiate Products in C# rather than in App.xaml and still have it available in every window?

Comment: @FSL_AU: there really is no point in writing a WPF program if you want to minimize the use of XAML. The whole point of WPF is to leverage XAML as much as possible. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with initializing the collection in C#, or in doing everything else in C#, but you lose a lot of the automatic behaviors WPF provides if you do so. You might as well just use Winforms if you want a primarily-imperative programming model.

Comment: @FSL_AU Yes, after all that is what the wpf runtime is doing after it parses the xml. But I don't have an example. Google "programmatic collectionviewsource" or something like that. But I still don't understand why don't want to do it declaratively.

Comment: The only reason for porting to WPF is to protect against the day when VB6 applications will no longer run on the current version of windows. The application works well and we are instructed to minimise changes in the code. There is no point in porting to WinForms as that technology also has a limited life.

Comment: xaml is also more verbose than C#. That is a disincentive.

Comment: It is a mistake. Vb6 to wpf is a complete rewrite, there is no minimizing code changes. If you simply try to translate vb6 to c# then you are not protecting against regression bugs. You are just architecting poorly.

Comment: @FSL_AU Regarding your comment: `The only reason for porting to WPF is to protect against the day when VB6 applications will no longer run` - It seems to me like you're in a team of VB6 developers trying to write a WPF application. Sorry I don't mean to be rude, but you will fail miserably. WPF is fundamentally different from VB6. Hire a developer with WPF (and MVVM) experience if you really care about your project.